# Sybase SQL Anywhere Database Management Tools

Tags: monitoring, sqlanywhere

What tools can I use to monitor performance, defragment, etc. a Sybase SQL Anywhere database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To defragment a SQL Anywhere database, you need to rebuild it. Look in the docs for the [dbunload -an switch](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.php#http%3A//dcx.sybase.com/1101en/dbusage_en11/designing-rebuild-extract.html).

As for performance monitoring, in version 11.x, the [Sybase Central Performance Monitor](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.php#http%3A%2F%2Fdcx.sybase.com%2F1101en%2Fdbusage_en11%2Fpfsc.html) was introduced.

*Full disclosure*: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Breck Carter's [Foxhound](http://www.risingroad.com/foxhound/foxhound1_help/foxhound_introduction.html). It was built specifically for SQL Anywhere. I'm not sure it supports version 11, but as Graeme said there are built-in monitoring tools for that version.

If file fragmentation is an issue, my experience with dbunload is that the rebuilt database files will also be fragmented to some extent. What you can do is stop the database server and run Sysinternal's [contig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx) against the .db and .log files.

Comment: Sadly, Beta 9 of Foxhound is closed, and Beta 10 won't be starting until next year... BUT, Foxhound is in active development and planned for GA release after Beta 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for more of a health and availability monitoring tool, you might also want to look at the [SQL Anywhere Monitor](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.php#http%3A%2F%2Fdcx.sybase.com%2F1101en%2Fdbadmin_en11%2Fintro-sam.html), introduced in version 11.0.1.

(Full disclosure: Like Graeme, I also work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering)